# Rubocop -> Use a guard clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rubocop

What is the best way to fix my formatting to avoid the rubocop error?  Or is there a way to modify rubocop? Which is best?

Error

> Style/GuardClause: Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code
>   inside a conditional expression.
>       if @saved_search.save

Code

```
   if @saved_search.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to saved_searches_path }
        format.js {}
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only this behaviour (without consider the "else") so you could do in this format:

```rb
return unless @saved_search.save

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to saved_searches_path }
  format.js {}
end
```

But I suggest you to add an `else` clause to take care when the save returns `false`.